# Every vector space has a basis proof using Zorn's lemma in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

**Every vector space has a basis proof  by using Zorn's lemma.**
How will I prove this statement by using [Zorn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma)?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165684/while-proving-that-every-vector-space-has-a-basis-why-are-only-finite-linear-co?rq=1

Comment: A basis is a maximal linearly independent set under the $\subseteq$-ordering.

Comment: I downvoted. I think the asker should put some more effort. I will gladly reverse my downvote if the question gets edited accordingly.

Answer (score 22):

The poset involved is the set of all linearly independent subsets, ordered by inclusion, i.e. $A\le B$ iff $A\subseteq B$.  The problem is to show that there is a maximal such linearly independent subset.  Zorn's lemma says this is true if every chain of linearly independent subsets has an upper bound.  So the question is where to find such an upper bound.  I claim the union of the members of the chain will serve.  If a set of linearly independent subsets is linearly ordered by inclusion, then their union is also linearly independent.  To show this, one must recall that a set is linearly independent precisely if every **finite** linear relation among them is trivial.  I.e. linear independence is a property that has "finite character".

At this point, I will leave the details as an exercise.

**Later note:** In view of Brian M. Scott's comment below: If a linearly independent set fails to span the space, then there's some vector that is not a linear combination of finitely many members of that set.  Add it to the linearly independent set, getting a bigger linearly independent set.  It follows that every linearly independent set that fails to span the space is not maximal.  Hence every maximal one spans the space.

Comment: Showing that there is a maximal linear independent set is only half of if: one must still show that a maximal lin. indep. set spans the space.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : I've added something on that above.

Comment: Looks good now. +1

Comment: I said "every finite linear relation among them is trivial".  One could also say "Every finite linear dependence among them is zero".  A linear dependence among vectors $\vec{v}_1,\ldots,\vec{v}_n$ is a tuple of scalars $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ such that $\sum_k c_k \vec{v}_k=\vec{0}$.  One can show that two linear dependences are really the same dependence if one of them is a nonzero scalar multiple of the other; hence the set of linear dependences is a projective space.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : It seems to me that that "half" of the problem is much less than half: it's quite simple by comparison to the other "half".

Answer (score 0):

A dual approach to this proof is to consider the set of subsets of a vector space $V$ that generate $V$, ordered by reverse inclusion. Consider any chain and take the intersection to produce an upper bound. Since this is a nested intersection, it is still a generating set, so it is contained in our set. Thus by Zorn's lemma, there is a minimal generating set, which is an equivalent definition of a basis.

Comment: This argument doesn’t work, as the intersection of a nested sequence of generating set need not generate. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078969/intersection-of-totally-ordered-set-of-spanning-sets-is-still-spanning/3079022#3079022)